# Origin moves instead of actual object in blender 2.9

Tags: transforms

Origin moves instead of actual object in blender 2.9. Same applies to Rotation and Scale also. It was not so in previous versions. Tried the solution given to question raised by Nyx. But still it is not working.

Old answers not working, in my version, Transform affects only the Origins is also Off / Unchecked.

Comment: Hello :). This can have multiple reasons, please share your file so others can take a look :).

Comment: yea, if you share your file it will make it a lot easier for people to help you.  Especially for a question like this.

Comment: I start blender 2.91, default cube is there, without pressing anything, just use move transform, nothing happens except an orange dot (origin) moving. I checked the Transform affect only, all the three check boxes of Origins, Locations and Parents are unchecked also. Kindly download latest blender, install and run it, you can note it